# IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, web-crawler, ioerror

I'm new to python. When I tried to run a crawler that just fetches the links in a page, I got this error.I have python 2.7 installed and working on osx. What my crawler does is, it goes to page and tries to find all the links present in that page and stores all those links in a list. Next we try to crawl all the new links, and continue to repeat the same till there are no links to crawl.

```
 File "crawler.py", line 44, in <module>
 print crawl_web("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_May_Cry_4")
 File "crawler.py", line 7, in crawl_web
   union(tocrawl,get_all_links(get_page(page)))
 File "crawler.py", line 19, in get_page
   response = urllib.urlopen(a)
 File" /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
return opener.open(url)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 469, in open_file
return self.open_local_file(url)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 483, in open_local_file
raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'/w/load.phpdebug=false&amp;lang=en&amp;
modules=ext.cite.styles|ext.gadget.DRN-wizard,ReferenceTooltips,charinsert,featured-
articleslinks,refToolbar,switcher,teahouse|ext.wikimediaBadges&amp;only=styles&amp;
skin=vector'
```

Here's the code that I ran

```
def crawl_web(page):
  tocrawl = [page]
  crawled = []
  while tocrawl:
     page = tocrawl.pop()
     if page not in crawled:
         union(tocrawl,get_all_links(get_page(page)))
         crawled.append(page)
     return crawled

def union(a,b):
 for e in b:
    if e not in a:
        a.append(e)

import urllib
def get_page(a):
 response = urllib.urlopen(a)
 data = response.read()
return data

def get_all_links(page):
 links = []
 while True:
    url,endpos = get_next_target(page)
    if url:
        links.append(url)
        page = page[endpos:]
    else:
        break
return links

def get_next_target(page):
  start_link = page.find('href=')
  if start_link == -1:
    return None,0
  start_quote = page.find('"',start_link)
  end_quote = page.find('"',start_quote+1)
  url = page[start_quote +1:end_quote]
  return url,end_quote


print crawl_web("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_May_Cry_4")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is flawed. Links in html may be relative, e.g. `/index.php` `//en.wikipedia.org/index.php`, thus you have to detect relative links and add protocol and host prefix.